# Showing that a relation cannot have non-trivial MVDs

Tags: relational-database, rdbms, database-normalization

I`ve got a relation "Trips" with:

```
Person | Destination | Vehicle
Alex   | Uni         | Bike
Zora   | Uni         | Bike
Alex   | Dentist     | Bike
Alex   | Uni         | Bus.
```

Now I need to show that "Trips" cannot have non-trivial MVDs.
I know that a MVD A ->>B is trivial if A u B together form the whole relation, or if B is part of A.

My idea so far: There would be 3 types of possible MVDs:

1. (Pers, Dest, Veh) ->>Pers, (Pers, Dest, Veh) ->>Dest, (Pers, Dest, Veh) ->>Veh. These are trivial because the right side is part of the left side.
2. (Pers, Dest) ->> Veh, (Pers, Veh) ->> Dest, (Dest, Veh) ->> Pers. 
   These are also trivial because both sides together form the whole relation.
3. Pers ->> Dest, Pers ->> Veh, Dest ->> Veh, Dest ->> Pers, Veh ->> Dest, Veh ->> Pers.
   These just wouldn´t make sense since a MVD´s "idea" is that the right side is somewhat independent from the other columns in the relation, an here this is not the case. 
   The only argument I can come up with is that if these were valid MVDs, there would also exist the tuple (Alex|Dentist|Bus) and since it doesn´t, they aren´t valid MVDs. But only because that tuple isn´t shown doesn´t mean it can´t be, does it?
   How would I actually proof my idea? 
   Or could I somehow proof that these would also be trivial?

Comment: Re 'a MVD´s "idea" is that the right side is somewhat independent from the other columns in the relation': That doesn't mean anything. You need to find a *definition* of MVD and the definition of when an MVD holds in a relation. Then for a particular MVD show that the example data contradicts the claim that it holds. Your "if these were valid MVDs" (ie MVDs that hold) is in the right direction but you need to find a separate contradicting tuple for each one.

Comment: Why do you think those are the only MVDs that you need to test? There is an MVD for every pair of subsets of attributes.